# nested if else statement gives incorrect results and not run

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement

I am trying to create a log file system with an index in it.
for every 100 lines in the log file, the log file should recreate to log1.log , for every 1000 files created the index1.log recreate to index2.log

```
if (timesrun % 100 != 0)
{
    Debug.Write(" enter code here. ");
    if (timesrun % 1000 != 0)
    {
        Debug.Write("'");
        Debug.Write(" enter code here. ");
     }
    else
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("rename files index?.xml ");
        string basename = "index";
        string extention = ".log";
        crntstmap++;
        nowsitemap = basename + crntstmap + extention;
        Debug.WriteLine(nowsitemap);
                        }
    //call method create actual file using the filename + timesrun IE
}
else
{
    Debug.WriteLine("rename files log?.php ");
    string basename = "log";
    string extention = ".log";
    crntindx++;
    nowindex = basename + crntindx + extention;
    Debug.WriteLine(nowindex);
}
```

I am getting strange results, the second part of the if loop never runs and I never see `Debug.WriteLine(nowsitemap);`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to accomplish, but the reason execution never enters that branch is because it isn't possible for a number to not be a multiple of `100` *yet* be a multiple of `1000`. `100` is a factor of `1000`.

```
if(timesrun % 100 != 0 && timesrun % 1000 == 0) // Always false
{
    Debug.WriteLine("rename files index?.xml ");
    string basename = "index";
    ...
```

Comment: so should i drop the loop below the other loop ? how do i get both to run?

Answer (score 1):

Basically your comparisons are inverted. This:

```
if (timesrun % 100 != 0)
```

will run 99 times out of a hundred, not *one* time out of a hundred.

You meant:

```
if (timesrun % 100 == 0)
```

and likewise for the 1000 case... although that will then roll over the files every *10* files, not every *1000* files, as you'll be doing it after 1000 *lines*. You could either make this 100000, or change to have one variable for lines and one for files.

(Note that the structure of your code would also be a lot clearer if you lines up your indentation appropriately.)

Answer (score 0):

because `if timesrun % 100 != 0` so always `timesrun % 1000` will be `not 0`